# How to verify the tooltip message in table using selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have to verify the tool tip message displayed in a table using selenium web driver.I have taken the actions class and used build.perform() but it returns an empty string. The problem is , html code is in such a way that the tool tip tags are incorporated with the span tag. Please let me know how to resolve this issue.

HTML code : [image]

```
<span class="abcd" data-qtip="<table><tr><td>xxx as of 05/04/2017  </td><td>$1.00</td></tr><tr><td>yyy</td><td>$1.00</td></tr><tr><tdzzz</td><td>$0.00</td></tr><tr><td>xyz</td><td>0.00%</tr></td></table>"/>
```

xxx,yyy,zzz and xyz are the texts I need to verify.

Method I used:

```
public void mouseOver(String loc) {
    Actions ToolTip1 = new Actions(driver);
    WebElement pr = findElement(loc);
    System.out.println(pr);
    pause(2000);
    ToolTip1.moveToElement(pr).perform();
    pause(2000);
    String toolTipMsg = pr.getText();
    pause(1000);
    System.out.println(toolTipMsg);
}
```

where loc = xpath of the element.

Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: Please format the HTML so that it's not one long line to make it easier to read. You haven't included the locators that you have tried. Please add a tag for the language that you are looking for an answer in. it looks like you are using Java?

Comment: have you tried simply finding the span and getting the value of the `data-qtip` attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing mousehover to the webelement, use the getAttribute method to get the value of "data-qtip". Below line can help you.

```
String toolTip = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='abcd']")).getAttribute("data-qtip").toString();
```

Store the expected message in another string and compare that with toolTip.

Since in this case, the string toolTip is in Html and we need to parse it to required format and compare it to the expected string. The below code parses the toolTip and gives the String which needs to be validated.

```
System.out.println(toolTip);
String[] word1 = toolTip.split("<td>");
String a = word1[1].split(" ")[0];
System.out.println(a);
String b = word1[3].split("</")[0];
System.out.println(b);
String c = word1[6].split("</")[0];
System.out.println(c);
String d = word1[4].split("<td")[1].split("<")[0];
System.out.println(d);
```

We can even parse it a better way but this works. Later validate a, b, c, d with the expected messages. Thanks

Comment: I don't think you need to do the mouseover to get the attribute, unless the attribute is set only on mouseover.

Comment: it depends on the application

Comment: @santhosh kumar : I tried your suggestion. But it's returning the html tags like below :                                                                                                              
                                                                                                      
<table><tr><td>XXX as of 05/05/2017  </td><td>$1.00</td></tr><tr><td>YYY</td><td>$1.00</td></tr><tr><td>ZZZ</td><td>$0.00</td></tr><tr><td>XYZ</td><td>0.00%</tr></td></table> ...But I wanted to check xxx,yyy,zzz etc ..

Comment: @Rahul what getText() is returning instead of toString.    String toolTip = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='abcd']")).getAttribute("data-qtip").getText();

Comment: getText() is not supported with getAttribute  :  String toolTipMsg = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.rabcd")).getAttribute("data-qtip").getText();                                                                                                            throws error....

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
Actions ToolTip1 = new Actions(driver);
WebElement pr = findElement(loc);
System.out.println(pr);
ToolTip1.moveToElement(pr).perform();
pause(2000);
String toolTipMsg =     driver.findElement(by.cssSelector("span.abcd")).getAttribute("data-qtip");
System.out.println(toolTipMsg);
```

Comment: Code only answers are not allowed on SO. Please take a minute to summarize what your code does and how it answers the question.

Comment: @Kushal : This is also returning empty string. :(

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a better solution and i came up with this.

Step 1: Store the result in a string,

```
String Tooltip = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='abcd']")).getAttribute("data-qtip").toString();
```

Step 2: Use some regex pattern to get the data only from "td" tags and add it to a ArrayList.

```
ArrayList<String> lists = new ArrayList<>();
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(<td>(.*?)<\\/td>)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(toolTip);
while(m.find()) 
{
    String tag2 = m.group(1);
    String tag = tag2.substring(4,(tag2.length()-5)); //removes the <td> and </td> tags in the matched string
    lists.add(tag);
    System.out.println(tag);
}
```

Now the lists will have all the table data's. Iterate through the list elements and compare it to the expected String. Thanks.